# FLV stream repack for http streaming

Tags: node.js, video, flv

I have mediaserver based on http protocol and node.js. It receive any flv stream from broadcast computer with ffmpeg, like this (camcapture is internal console tool):

```
$ camcapture -f mpegts - | ffmpeg -i - -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f flv http://mediaserver/publish_url
```

I want restream this flv stream to clients via http. How I should regenerate flv data for each new client?

Comment: can you give us sample code, in particular the one that calls this command line. gist would be nice.